# Update Google reCaptcha from v2 to v3

Tags: recaptcha

We are using google Google reCaptcha V2 in couple of out applications. We need to upgrade few of them to v3 and keep others on v2.

So when updating for v3 we need to create key pairs for our domain we used for v2.

My question is 
- Is there any impact on v2 Google reCaptcha keys when generating keys for v3 for the same domain? In other words can the same domain have keys for both v2 and v3 with out any impact to each other ?

**Note - If first applications of v3 migration successful we can migrate rest of apps to v3**